# 2 Rows In My Java Function Do Not Want To Execute In Android App

Tags: android, user-interface, handler

I have a function that runs a task periodically with the help of a Handler, in the background. Part of that periodically executed code is changing the UI, thus I am running it in the main thread. The code runs, but 2 lines of the code (that change the UI) seem like get never executed. Please, see the comments in the code below for more details.

```
     public void startTimerForRefreshingSensorsData(Integer mins) {
        if (handlerRefresh == null) {
            final int delay = mins * 60000;//milliseconds
            final TextView refreshes = findViewById(R.id.number_of_autorefreshes);
            final TextView refreshes_time = findViewById(R.id.autorefresh_time);
            refreshes.setText("Autorefreshes:" + numberOfAutoRefreshes);
            final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy, HH:mm");
            handlerThread = new HandlerThread("refreshThread");
            handlerThread.start();
            handlerRefresh = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
            //Running the handler
            handlerRefresh.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    readJsonFromMultipleSensorsUrlAndStoreAsSharedpreference();
                    lastAutoRefreshTimeSensorList = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    numberOfAutoRefreshes += 1;
                    // Stuff that updates the UI should run on main thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            displaySavedSensorsFromSharedPreferences(); //LOOK LIKE THIS DOES NOT EXECUTE, UI NOT CHANGING
                            refreshes_time.setText("Last refresh: " + lastAutoRefreshTimeSensorList);
                            refreshes.setText("Autorefreshes:" + numberOfAutoRefreshes); //THIS DOES NOT EXECUTE, UI NOT CHANGING
                            Log.d("REFRESH HANDLER", "Some stuff ran on the UI thread"); //THIS LINE EXECUTES, I get a message in the log ???
                        }
                    });
                    Log.d("REFRESH HANDLER", "The " + numberOfAutoRefreshes + " handler has been run at: " + df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
                    handlerRefresh.postDelayed(this, delay);
                }
            }, delay);
        }
    }
```

This method is called in the onCreate function of the activity. LMK if any other info is needed...

P.S.
I believe the function displaySavedSensorsFromSharedPreferences(); causes some issues that I can't figure out, here is its code:

````
        Log.d("JSONException)", "************************ START ALL *********************************");
        ListView sensorsListView = findViewById(R.id.sensorsView);
        //Get the saved sensors list  //TODO - what happens when NULL ???
        ArrayList<String> list = getSavedSensorsList();
        Log.d("JSONException)", "Getting the saved sensors list "+list);
        //Set up all arrays with data for the sensors list
        int lSize = list.size();
        Log.d("JSONException)", "The size of the list is "+lSize);
        String[] idsArr = new String[lSize];
        Log.d("JSONException)", "String array -isdArr- of size "+idsArr.length+" generated");
        idsArr = list.toArray(idsArr);
        Log.d("JSONException)", "String array populated with list values");
        Integer[] iconIdsArr = new Integer[lSize];  //TODO - add logic for generating this Integer[] array and remove it from the dummy generation in the FOR loop below
        Log.d("JSONException)", "String array -iconIdsArr- of size "+iconIdsArr.length+" generated");
        Log.d("JSONException)", "Generating values arrays:");
        String[] valuesArr = new String[lSize];
        Log.d("JSONException)", "ValuesArr- size "+valuesArr.length);
        String[] valueTypesArr = new String[lSize];
        Log.d("JSONException)", "valueTypesArr- size "+valueTypesArr.length);
        String[] valuesArr2 = new String[lSize];
        Log.d("JSONException)", "valuesArr2- size "+valuesArr2.length);
        String[] valueTypesArr2 = new String[lSize];
        Log.d("JSONException)", "valueTypesArr2- size "+valueTypesArr2.length);

        //Populate the set arrays
        Log.d("JSONException)", "Populating arrays");
        for (int i=0; i<lSize;i++) {
            Log.d("JSONException)", ".............START SENSOR "+list.get(i)+"................");
            String sensorJsonString = readAStringPreference(list.get(i));
            Log.d("JSONException)", "Starting extracting the JSON string for sensor "+list.get(i));
            Log.d("JSONException)", "JSON string: "+sensorJsonString);
            if (!sensorJsonString.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("JSONException)", "Passed IF, the JSON string is not NULL");
                try {
                    JSONArray jar2 = new JSONArray(sensorJsonString);
                    Log.d("JSONException)", "Creating the JSON array from the string for sensor "+list.get(i));
                    valuesArr[i] = jar2.getJSONObject(0).getString("value");
                    valueTypesArr[i] = jar2.getJSONObject(0).getString("value_type");
                    Log.d("JSONException)", valuesArr[i] +" "+ valueTypesArr[i]);

                    valuesArr2[i] = jar2.getJSONObject(1).getString("value");
                    valueTypesArr2[i] = jar2.getJSONObject(1).getString("value_type");
                    Log.d("JSONException)", valuesArr2[i] +" "+ valueTypesArr2[i]);
                    iconIdsArr[i] = 1;  //TODO - check the upper TODO
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    displayMessageIfDebuggingOn("There is a JSON exception, check the logs...");
                    Log.d("JSONException)", "JSON throwing some exception...");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("JSONException", "JSON for sensor "+list.get(i)+" is EMPTY, ENDING CYCLE!!!");
            }
            Log.d("JSONException)", ".............END SENSOR "+list.get(i)+"................");
            Log.d("JSONException)", "");
        }
        Log.d("JSONException)", "*************************END ALL***************************************");
        Log.d("JSONException)", "");

        //Apply custom adapter to populated data
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,  idsArr, iconIdsArr, valuesArr, valueTypesArr, valuesArr2, valueTypesArr2);
        sensorsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        View headerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.sensors_list_header, null, false);
        if (sensorsListView.getHeaderViewsCount() < 1) {
            sensorsListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        }
    }```


Thanks!
````

Comment: I bet if you set a breakpoint on the line, you could see in great detail what was executing, and what was not.

Comment: Yes, I set a breakpoint and it seems everything gets executed! But the UI does NOT change...wtf...

Comment: This type of thing is usually because `refreshes` does not represent the object you are looking at on the screen. It's a stale object, taken from an earlier layout.

Comment: Hm... But sometimes it works, so if your assumption is right, it will never work, in all of the cases. But this thing works sometimes and sometimes not...

Comment: A.) how many times is `startTimerForRefreshingSensorsData()` executing, and B.) how do you know that?

Comment: It's executed when the activity is loaded, in the onCreate method, normally just once. Sometimes more  if the activity gets reloaded. 
 I believe it's something with the data (JSON) that  displaySavedSensorsFromSharedPreferences()  reads, because it's the only thing that's dynamic an changes... Or it's something with the Handler class, probably I iwll try to replace it with the Service one... from what I am reading, it seems it's much more reliable for background services...

Comment: So if `onCreate()` executes a second time, then `handlerRefresh` is non-null, and `startTimerForRefreshingSensorsData()` will do nothing. Meanwhile, your old `handlerThread` is still chugging along. And what value of `refreshes` do you think it is using? The one instantiated during your _most recent_ call to `setContentView()`, or the one from your _first_ call to `setContentView()`?

Comment: Here's a hint: Dump the value of `refreshes.isShown()` to logcat after every time you call `setText()` on it. See if the value changes to `false` during those times it is not working.

Comment: I have this row:    Log.d("REFRESH HANDLER", "Some stuff ran on the UI thread"); in the main thread' so I know when the  UI part is reached. This row gets executed while the other 2 don't for some reason, that's the strange stuff here. Also, If the handler is already started on execution, the 'old handler thread' is reading from a json string in the preferences. It's possible that string not to be changed, but then the handler has to update the: View:lastAutoRefreshTimeSensorList with the system time of execution. This is not updated either. will try your hint tmrow, thanks for trying to help.